# Cómo validar campo select con JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

¿Cómo puedo validar en un campo `select` que al seleccionar una opción haga `x` función? Intenté hacerlo pero no funcionó. ¿Alguna forma de hacerlo?

```
registerGenderCheck = false;
$(function() {
    $('#registergender').on('click', function() {
        var x = $('#registergender');
        var bt = $('.button');

        if(x.val()){
            registerGenderCheck = true;
            x.css('border', '1px solid #40de49');
        }
        // else {}
    });
});

<select id="registergender">
    <option value="">Selecciona tu género</option>
    <option value="">Masculino</option>
    <option value="">Femenino</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres debes cambiar la forma en la que intentas capturar el cambio de valor del elemento `select`, debes utilizar el evento `change` y no `click`, de la siguiente forma:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#registergender').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'masculino'){
      $(this).css('border', '1px solid #40de49');
    }else{
      $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="registergender">
  <option value="">Selecciona tu género</option>
  <option value="masculino">Masculino</option>
  <option value="femenino">Femenino</option>
</select>
```

En el código **HTML** de tu `select`, te faltaba asignar los `value` de cada `option`.

Comment: Gracias amigo, funciona excelente :).

Comment: @Snowstorm me alegra que te funcionara, te invito a finalizar la pregunta marcando la respuesta como aceptada ya que esto servirá también a otros desarrolladores que lleguen a tener el mismo inconveniente